# Remove old IAP purchase requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I was testing an IAP transaction a few months ago, but my device prompts me multiple times per day to enter the password.  (pretty sure the account is gone).  Have tried reloading the OS (didn't think that would work), so trying to find a way to clear my queue.

Comment: See `SKPaymentQueue finishTransaction:`.